# Syntax explanation for Custom LeafSystem using TemplateSystem

Tags: drake

I am trying to create a custom `LeafSystem` capable of converting between scalar types.

I have been trying to understand the following code so I can create my own:

```
@TemplateSystem.define("MySystem_")
def MySystem_(T):

    class Impl(LeafSystem_[T]):
        def _construct(self, value, converter=None):
            LeafSystem_[T].__init__(self, converter=converter)
            self.value = value

        def _construct_copy(self, other, converter=None):
            Impl._construct(self, other.value, converter=converter)

    return Impl

MySystem = MySystem_[None]  # Default instantiation.
```

I am not a strong python programmer so I apologize if some of these questions are python syntax questions rather than drake.

1. I am unfamiliar with the following syntax and I am unsure what exactly this is doing:
   `@TemplateSystem.define("MySystem_")`
2. Why is the `Impl` class contained in `MySystem_`?
3. If I want to implement my own functions like I would in a normal `LeafSystem` would they be defined in `Impl`?
4. I am also unsure how exactly the type conversion is being implemented. Lets say I define a system `MySystem = MySystem_[float]`. However I also want to use this system to create a `DirectCollocation`. Does `DirectCollocation` know how to call `_construct_copy` and convert it to an `AutoDiffXd` or do I need to type convert myself before hand?

Additionally, any examples that use `TemplateSystem` would help out a lot and seeing how they are used I think would clear up a lot of my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a note - keep in mind that Python does not have an actual concept of "templates" in the same way as C++. Instead, we have custom-built Python components for Drake to more closely reflect the C++ API by mimicking templates, similar to things like `cppyy`.

#### Explanation

TBD. Will edit this in.

#### References

For docs on motivation for templates:

- https://drake.mit.edu/python_bindings.html#scalar-types
- https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.scalar_conversion.html

Examples in Russ's course notes:

- https://github.com/RussTedrake/underactuated/search?q=TemplateSystem

If it helps, here are the unittests exercising the feature:

- https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/v1.5.0/bindings/pydrake/common/test/cpp_param_test.py
- https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/v1.5.0/bindings/pydrake/common/test/cpp_template_test.py
- https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/v1.5.0/bindings/pydrake/systems/test/scalar_conversion_test.py